# HighCharts dynamically resize renderer label or element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, highcharts

I need to add extensive footnotes to my charts and they must export with svg so I cannot simply put them in the surrounding HTML.

I have tried several strategies and I can position it, wrap text, manipulate the size of the chart to make space etc.

The intent is to make them responsive.
The problem is I cant find how to update the size of the container that holds this text either using using events and renderer elements or using chart.labels

In this fiddle (among other things):
I am attempting to create a new label with every redraw but I cannot find how to address and destroy the label I am creating with the onload

http://jsfiddle.net/alex_at_pew/qswnw4wz/2/

```
$(function () {
function foo() { var width = $(this.container).width()-250; return width;}
var footnote_text = 'This text will adjust to chart resizing This text will adjust to chart resizing This text will adjust to chart resizing This text will adjust to chart resizing This text will adjust to chart resizing This text will adjust to chart resizing This text will adjust to chart resizing This text will adjust to chart resizing This text will adjust to chart resizing This text will adjust to chart resizing This text will adjust to chart resizing This text will adjust to chart resizing This text will adjust to chart resizing ';
$('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
        events: {


            load: function () {
                var label = this.renderer.label(footnote_text, //str
                        10, //x
                        200,//y
                        'rect',//shape
                        1,//anchorX
                        1,//anchorY
                        1,//useHTML
                        1,//baseline
                        'deletme'//className
                    )
                    .css({
                    width: foo() + 'px'

                }).add();

            },
            redraw: function () {
            $('.highcharts-deletme').remove();
               console.log('chart');
                var label = this.renderer.label(footnote_text, //str
                        10, //x
                        200,//y
                        'rect',//shape
                        1,//anchorX
                        1,//anchorY
                        1,//useHTML
                        1,//baseline
                        'deletme'//className
                    )
                    .css({
                    width: foo() + 'px'

                }).add();
            }
        }
    },
    labels: {

        items: [{
            html:  foo()+footnote_text
        }],
        style: {
            left: '100px',
            top: '100px',
            color: 'red',
            width: foo()
        }
    },series: [{
       data: [29.9, 71.5]     
       }]

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Another (and general) solution is to store generated label in a variable:

```
var myLabel; // define label
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
       events: {
          load: function () {
              myLabel = this.renderer.label( ... ).add();
          },
          redraw: function () {
              if(myLabel) {
                    myLabel.destroy();
              }
              myLabel = this.renderer.label( ... ).add();
          }
       }
    }
});
```

It will be faster, than using jQuery to find items by classes.

Comment: Thanks Pawel, but this is something that needs to be done in addition to what I do. It destroys the object but it does not delete the html.

Comment: you are right. I was not defining the variable first `var myLabel; // define label` Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out highcharts lets you add a class to the label.

```
var label = this.renderer.label(
     footnote_text, //str
     10,  //x
     200, //y
     'rect', //shape
     1, //anchorX
     1, //anchorY
     1, //useHTML
     1, //baseline
     'deleteme' //className
)
```

I've added a class name `deleteme` and then used jQuery to delete it:

```
$('.highcharts-deletme').remove();
```

Comment: Yes I figured out how to re-size an element. I will have to pose a different question on SO to tackle how to make space for it after re-size. Essentially Highcharts (the best charting software I have tested by the way) is designed to make a charts for you, not so much to help you manipulate an existing ones from a design stand point. Series, axes...yea great. Margins, footnotes, extraneous stuff...somewhat.

Comment: I had to use the className attr: $("[className='deleteme']").remove();